# How to prevent duplicating entities during entity updates?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I'm developing a .NET-based web server and encountering a issue. There's a one-to-one relationship between two entities, referred to as D and P. I'm currently working on implementing a PUT endpoint to update entity D. To accomplish this, I pass an instance of D, along with the corresponding instance of P, to the following method:

```
    public virtual async Task<TEntity> Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        if (entityToUpdate == null)
        {
            throw new BadRequestException(GenericErrors.NULL_ARGUMENT, new string[] { typeof(TEntity).ToString() });
        }

        var entry = context.Entry(entityToUpdate);

        entityToUpdate.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            var set = context.Set<TEntity>();

            TEntity attachedEntity = await set.FindAsync(entityToUpdate.Id);  // You need to have access to key

            //Set Previous DateCreated
            entityToUpdate.DateCreated = attachedEntity.DateCreated;

            if (attachedEntity != null)
            {
                var attachedEntry = context.Entry(attachedEntity);
                attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entityToUpdate);
            }
            else
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified; // This should attach entity
            }
        }

        return entityToUpdate;
    }
```

But each time a new instance of P is added (even if the instance of D references a pre-existing instance of P). How can I solve this issue? I'm new with .NET :)

Comment: Why is this code used in the first place? If the entity's PK is database generated, `DbContext.Update` will start tracking an object in either the `Modified` or `Added` state based on whether the PK has a value or not. Even if the key is client supplied, eg a GUID, all you need is to check for existence, not load the entire object. Worst case you could use `if (context.Products.Any(p=>p.Id=45) { context.Update(object); } else {context.Add(object);}`.

Comment: As for related entities, again, what are the *specifics*? If you *don't* use db-generated keys, EF can't guess whether P and D exist or not, so it will track *both* objects in the same state, unless you add explicit code to track each one separately.